# Bluetooth chat Android two way communication

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I've tried building an app using Android open source Bluetooth chat sample project. you can find the source code here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

The problem is that the sample itself has a bug sometimes two way communication fail and one of the two devices fail to receive messages
you can find the problem in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVyW7yBBwa0&t=4m16s

I've tested it using Samsung GT-N7000 running 4.1.2 and Samsung Galaxy Mega running KitKat.

Can anyone help me figure out how can I edit the source code to fix this bug as the two devices fail two way communication each time I try to connect them using the app.

I've used Android Studio to build the signed apk.